# Adding element to slice in handlerfunc and return as a whole

Tags: go, slice

I'm writing a service to learn Go. My main function can be found below. It starts with reading an XML file and storing them in a slice. I have a `/rss` endpoint which outputs a RSS feed from the items stored in the "database". This is working fine. I also have an endpoint (`/add/{base64}`) which is used to add a new item to that slice. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. For some reason I need to return the new `database` with the added record, so it gets available to the `/rss`. But how?

My concrete problem is:

1. I know how to add a record to `database`
2. But I don't know how to return the full (including the added) database so the `/rss` endpoint is able to use it. So I want to let the `rest.AddArticle` return the new database so the `/rss` endpoint knows the added item.

   ```
   func main() {
   defer glog.Flush()

   // read database
   database := model.ReadFileIntoSlice()

   // initialise mux router
   r := mux.NewRouter()

   // http handles
   r.HandleFunc("/add/{base64url}", rest.AddArticle(database))
   r.HandleFunc("/rss", rest.GenerateRSS(database))

   // start server
   http.Handle("/", r)
   glog.Infof("running on port %d", *port)
   http.ListenAndServe(":"+strconv.Itoa(*port), nil)
   }
   ```

Or is there some other solution which does the job? I just want `database` to be available through all packages.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If you request `/rss` once it will return all records in your database. Next your request `/add` and add a record. So if you request `/rss` once again after adding a record - all records include new one will be returned.

Comment: You don't mention where `mux.NewRouter` comes from, is it [gorilla](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#NewRouter)? You say "storing them in a slice" what is "them", does it matter or is just opaque objects?

Comment: The problem is when I add a record in my /add function, the added record is not available in the next call of my /rss function. I pass the `database` to my `rest.AddArticle` function, but it does not return anything. I think I need to let this function return the new database? @DaveC yes, I'm using Gorilla. You can find my problem here: https://github.com/rogierlommers/go-read/blob/master/go-read.go

Comment: There are likely better ways to do it, but you could just pass `&database` instead so that you can modify it. However, you need synchronization or you'll have deadly data races.

Comment: @daveC passing a pointer to the `database` indeed solved my problem. Thanks for that.

Comment: BTW, I don't see any synchronization with your changes, use the [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) to help identify your races and remove them. There is no such thing as a [benign data race](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) so do not ignore them. Your code also ignores errors in several places (e.g. from `os.Create`); never do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell the problem is that you're writing to your db but you're reading from the cached version so the response of rss just doesn't reflect the model at the time the request is made. If you look at this code;

```
database := model.ReadFileIntoSlice()

// initialise mux router
r := mux.NewRouter()

// http handles
r.HandleFunc("/add/{base64url}", rest.AddArticle(database))
```

you somehow need to modify the value of `database`. There are many ways you could do this. A few options would be 1) define it on some object or at a package level and then directly modify it from wherever `AddArticle` is defined. 2) refresh your in memory version, ie before you return the results, read from the db again so you're assured to have the latest (obv performance implications) 3) don't pass `database` by value, make the argument a pointer instead. `AddArticle` is getting a copy of `database` rather than the address to the version you're reading from in your rss call. You could instead pass a pointer into that method so that the original copy is modified (it also performs substantially better as your model gets larger).

Based on the simplicity of your program I'd probably do 3. Realistically 2 is a more robust solution and serious enterprise software probably would require something more along those lines (your model doesn't work if your app is load balanced or something like that).

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. It really helps a lot in learning Go! I have fixed my problem by applying your 3rd solution: using a pointer to the `database`.